# Chartit Module how to get the foreign key

Tags: django, django-models

I want to make a chart using the Polls example used on Django Doc. My problem is that I want to do it with each question. As of now I can show a pie chart with one question, but I realize that I am using one question.choice and the ids of the choices. But if I wan to use one question I cannot us id as one my arguments because it is going to get the question.id, not the choice.id. It is not easy for me to explain as clear.

Here is my code

```
def vote_results(request):
    #datapool with the data we want to retrieve
    votedata = DataPool(series=[{'options': {
        'source': Choice.objects.all()},
        'terms': [
        'id',
        'votes']}
        ])

    #Create chart object
    cht = Chart(
        datasource=votedata,
        series_options =
        [{'options':{
        'type': 'pie',
        'stacking': False},
        'terms':{
        'id': [
        'votes']
        }}],
        chart_options = 
          {'title': {
               'text': 'What team will win NBA champ?' }},
        x_sortf_mapf_mts = (None, monthname, False))
    #Send the chart object to the template
    return render_to_response('polls/votes.html', {'votesdata': cht})
```

My question is how do I use the Question.objects.all() to get the question, but also use the Choice for each question, so that when a user vote for a question, he can see the results for that question's choices? If I do that now I will show all the choices of all the questions.

Do you see what I am trying to ask?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do, but i try to help. So we have two models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
  question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')


class Choice(models.Model):
  question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

if you want to get all questions with choices on it, you have to make this request:

```
questions = Qustions.objects.all()
```

then in template should look something like this:

```
{% for question in questions %}
   <p>{{question.question_text}}</p>
   {% for choice in qustion.choice_set.all %}
      {{choiceschoice_text}}
   {% endfor%}
{% endfor %}
```

hope it helps you

Comment: That I understand, but if you look at this part votedata = DataPool(series=[{'options': {
        'source': Choice.objects.all()},
        'terms': [
        'id',
        'votes']}
        ])
I want to create a pie chart using the information from one question, and the results from choices. The DataPool has the information, so I do not have to use a forloop to open in my template.